# Who owns /var/log/tor logs? Can`t get tor to start

Tags: logging, permissions, tor

I compiled tor and installed it (on raspbian).
All I must do now is to start tor with `tor`.

But all I get is

```
Mar 15 16:51:36.713 [notice] Tor v0.2.7.6 running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.21-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.1k and Zlib 1.2.8.
Mar 15 16:51:36.716 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Mar 15 16:51:36.718 [notice] Read configuration file "/usr/local/etc/tor/torrc".
Mar 15 16:51:36.757 [notice] Based on detected system memory, MaxMemInQueues is set to 278 MB. You can override this by setting MaxMemInQueues by hand.
Mar 15 16:51:36.774 [notice] Opening OR listener on 0.0.0.0:443
Mar 15 16:51:36.778 [notice] Opening Directory listener on 0.0.0.0:80
Mar 15 16:51:36.000 [warn] Couldn't open file for 'Log notice file /var/log/tor/notices.log': Permission denied
Mar 15 16:51:36.000 [notice] Closing partially-constructed OR listener on 0.0.0.0:443
Mar 15 16:51:36.000 [notice] Closing partially-constructed Directory listener on 0.0.0.0:80
Mar 15 16:51:36.000 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to init Log options. See logs for details.
Mar 15 16:51:36.000 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
```

With `sudo tor` there's no problem and it runs smoothly but normally I don't have run tor as root.
Now I don´t know how to deal with the ownership of the logs. 
When I do `sudo chmod 777 -R /var/log/tor` tor runs but then there's less security.

```
root@Debian:/var/log# ls -al /usr/local/bin/tor
-rwxr-xr-x 1 debian-tor adm 2091616 Mär 15 14:58 /usr/local/bin/tor
```

Thanx!

Comment: Offtopic. not a programming question. We are not general software/configuration tech support.

Comment: Since you don't run tor as root, `/var/logs/tor` should be owned by `debian-tor`.  Then you can set sane permissions on that path.

Comment: `ls -al /var/log/tor` -> `drwxrws--- 2 debian-tor debian-tor 4096 Mär 15 06:25 tor`

Comment: `ls -al /var/log/tor/` -> `-rw-r----- 1 debian-tor debian-tor 20742 Mär 15 16:46 notices.log`

Comment: `ps aux | grep tor` while tor is running `torpi 936 86.0 1.0 6964 3876 pts/1 R+ 17:57 0:00 tor` The user torpi runs it, but torpi is also member of the group debian-tor.  `/etc/group` -> `debian-tor:x:113:torpi`

Comment: @drew010 Is that way correct? It didn't change a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Success! :-D
I changed the rights of the logs with `chmod 660 *`.
This is the result:

`-rw-rw---- 1 debian-tor debian-tor    25124 Mär 15 20:49 notices.log`.

And the log folder /var/log/tor

`drwxr-s---  2 debian-tor  debian-tor   4096 Mär 15 06:25 tor`

goes like this.

Thanx drew010!

But one question is for me. Is it okay or are the rights too risky?

Comment: Those permissions look good.  Anyone outside of that user/group should not be able to look in /var/log/tor and the log files themselves aren't world readable, and especially not world writable.

Comment: Ok. That's fine. Thank you.